# Connect to 802.1x WiFi with an NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc, wifi

I am trying to write NFC tags to be able to connect Android devices automatically to a WiFi network that has 802.1x network-based security.  I can do this easily with WEP, WPA, and WPA2-secured WiFi networks, but is it possible to do this for 802.1x?  If so, how do I do it?  Also, I am pretty sure I am misunderstanding 802.1x completely.